# In-App Purchase screen is not as expected for beta testing

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight, beta, in-app

I am testing an app via test flight right now. When I am testing the in-app purchase portion of the app, it asks me for my app store username and password. I was not expecting this (I was expecting the standard faceID or TouchID in-app purchase interface to come up).

The developer says I must enter in my password when prompted. I do not want to do this as I am expecting a different kind of experience.

The app the developer has uploaded is prompting me with this prompt:
https://d.pr/i/LGfZ5V
And is asking me for my password. Which I don’t want to give.

I would expect something like this instead:
https://d.pr/i/b4l4xg

Which is the normal in-app purchasing experience I am used to.

The developer says it is a limitation of test flight for beta apps. However, I am not sure. Does anyone here know if this is legitimate? Or is it something the developer just may not be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the correct experience when testing in-app purchases in a TestFlight version. That prompt comes from Apple when you initiate a purchase.

Comment: It’s not the fact of the app asking for my username and password. It’s that it is *not* coming up with the standard App Store purchasing interface ( the one that you use Face ID or Touch ID with).

Comment: It’s the same screen that shows in any TestFlight when initiating an in-app purchase. It doesn’t show the touch id screen. Likely because you are not actually making a purchase.

Answer (score -1):

> And is asking me for my password. Which I don’t want to give

You’re only talking to the App Store, so it’s hard to see what the issue is. But if your objections are insurmountable, then clearly you cannot be a TestFlight beta tester for this feature of the app — because that is how in-app purchase beta testing in TestFlight works.